# How to get a minimized app to foreground in flutter

Tags: flutter, background, foreground

I am working on an app which listen a socket event. When the the socket event is received and the app is in background(background), It should be foreground. I have tried different packages [here](https://pub.dev/packages/app_to_foreground):

`AppToForeground.appToForeground();`

but the code is not executed on while the app is on the background.
Any solution is appreciated

Comment: You can follow this dependency : **flutter_background_service: ^3.0.1**